# Test connection failed. Details: {0} Error in Power Automate for MS Forms Connector

Tags: error, power-automate, connection, microsoft-forms

I have a flow that is working fine but when I try to edit the flow, I am getting the below error.

[image]

Under the connections section, my connection is connected but in the flow, it shows an error.

What can be the cause of this error? I tried to remove my connection and added new connection but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved by creating a fresh connection which resolves cookies related issues, if you are using chrome then you can open guest account and login into Microsoft forms with your credentials and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to Power Automate. Go to Data > Connections. Find the connection that's used in your flow. Select Fix connections, and then update the credentials for your connection if there is a Fix connection message next to the Status column.